# String converted to Array. Modulo the value is incorrect

Tags: c++

```
char* array{};
string digit4;

cout << "Enter a 4 digit-integer : " << endl;
cin >> digit4;

cout << "The 4 digit-integer you have entered is : " << digit4 << endl;

array = &digit4[0];

cout << "Digit 1 is : " << array[0] << endl;

int digit1 = (array[0] + 7) % 10;

cout << digit1 << endl;

return
```

I tried to convert a string to an array and use the first digit of `array[0]` to a formula of `( array[0] + 7 ) % 10`. If I input `1234`, `( 1 + 7 ) % 10` should be 8 but I'm getting 6 instead of 8. Any help would be great. Thank you for reading.

Comment: The value of the characters that represent `'0'` through `'9'` do _not_ correspond with integers `0` through `9`. Try `int digit = (digit4[0] - '0' + 7) % 10;` and to better see what's going on, output the character's actual value: `cout << "Digit 1 is : " << (int)digit4[0] << endl;`

Comment: `'1'` is not the same as `1`.

Comment: There are no arrays in this code, just a string and a pointer.

Comment: *"You have to realize that characters and strings are just numbers, like everything else in the computer. When you write `'a'` in the source code, it is pre-processed into the number 97, which is an integer constant."* from [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5030541/12002570)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `array[0]` evaluates to the character code for the digit `'1'`, which is `49` in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Therefore, assuming that you are using ASCII, the expression

```
(array[0] + 7) % 10;
```

is equivalent to

```
(49 + 7) % 10
```

which is `6`.

If you want to get the value that is represented by the digit, then you can simply subtract `'0'` (which is the character code for the digit `'0'`, which is `48` in ASCII) from the character code of the digit.

Therefore, to solve your problem, you can simply change the line

```
int digit1 = (array[0] + 7) % 10;
```

to:

```
int digit1 = ( array[0] - '0' + 7 ) % 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `array[0]` is **49** in ascii, when you use `+` you convert it to `int` like `int(array[0])` which the result is **49**. you should convert `array[0]` to `int` number like [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647280/how-to-turn-char-of-2-into-integer-2-in-c)

Comment: The difference between a character code and the value that a digit represents has nothing to do with whether a value is an `int` or not. Both can be represented as `char` or `int`. A `char` is also an integer type.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes `char` is 1 byte `int` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c) mentioned, but when use `+` ,the char converted to `int` in ascii and the conversion result is 49 which cause the wrong problem. I edit my answer, hope there in no ambiguity

Comment: Yes, you are right that `array[0]` is a `char` and that it will get promoted to an `int` when used as an operand in the `+` operation. However, whether such a promotion takes place or not is not relevant in this case. As stated in my previous comment, both the character code and the value that a digit represents can be represented as a `char` and as an `int`, because both are integer types. Therefore, the title of the question you linked to ("Convert char to int in C and C++") is misleading....

Comment: .... Converting between a `char` and an `int` has nothing to do with converting between a character code and the value that a digit represents.